# Замена подстроки на введенную с клавиатуры. С++

Tags: c++, строки, подстрока

Мне необходимо написать функцию, которая должна найти в строке все последовательности букв "or" и заменить ее на введенную с клавиатуры последовательность.

Пример:
Дана строка: "Hello, World? World or what?"
Введено с клавиатуры: "222"
Должно выйти: "Hello, W222ld? W222ld 222 what?"

```
string Str_Change(string str){
        string stp2 = "or";      // что ищем    - фиксированное значение
        string str_change;       // на что заменим
        cin >> str_change;
        //..........................
        return str;
}
```

Comment: Вы наверно забыли код добавить вместо `//...`! А так в чем конкретно проблема? За вас функцию написать нужно или что?